# Android RealmList does not get updated?

Tags: android, realm

I am using Realm 3, and when I try to add a new object to list of object like

```
realm.insertOrUpdate(newInvoice);
```

it adds a new record successfully and i can see it using stetho, but when i try to get list of invoices (from another activity), it does not catch the last inserted invoice!

```
RealmResults<DBInvoiceReceipt> results = realm.where(DBInvoiceReceipt.class).findAll();
```

Any help would be highly appreciated guys.

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3732

Comment: That's impossible. I need to see more code to see the cause of the error.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I believe that is related to realm object that am using. I replaced the whole way of doing realm and I followed this tutorial [link](http://kboyarshinov.com/android/wrapping-realm-around-rxjava)

Comment: does that mean you went with the whole "homebrew your realm Rx support" thing as well?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes I did.

Comment: ah that's why, just use realmChangeListeners for UI thread, there is no guarantee that saving on Schedulers.io() is immediately reflected on the UI thread.